# how to save the xml tag result when we click on the save button?

Tags: android, android-layout

hi all i have xml code like below

```
<root>
<key>
<Question>Is the color of the car</Question>
<Ans>black?</Ans>
</key>
<key>
<Question>Is the color of the car</Question>
<Ans>black?</Ans>
</key>
<key>
<Question>Is the news paper </Question>
<Ans>wallstreet?</Ans>
</key>
<key>
<Question>fragrance odor</Question>
<Ans>Lavendor?</Ans>
</key>
<key>
<Question>Is the baggage collector available</Question>
<Ans></Ans>
</key>
</root>
```

Display on the screen as:

List form
Is the color of the car black? Check box
Is the baggage collector available? Check box

if the check box is checked - Yes otherwise vlaue is no.
on save button: we need to save it into a xml file

here i am getting question with answer when i am checked but my problem is how to save checked list items into the xml file after click on the save button so give me the solution any one of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to the [Creating XML] section in [Working with XML on Android] at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html. Once you have the XML generated, you can save it to a file with the help of File and Stream classes.